# How does the Finite Ramsey Theorem imply the existence of Ramsey numbers

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

The textbook that I'm using to learn combinatorial set theory, *Combinatorial Set Theory With A Gentle Introduction To Forcing*, has this purely set-theoretic definition of The Finite Ramsey Theorem which doesn't appear anywhere else I search (all that pops up is the Graph Theory definition). I just want to understand how this definition actually pertains to the existence of a Ramsey Number for every set of two natural numbers. The definition they provide is as follows:

COROLLARY 2.3 (FINITE RAMSEY THEOREM). For all m,n,r ∈ ω, where r ≥ 1
and n ≤ m, there exists an N ∈ ω, where N ≥ m, such that for every colouring of
[N]^n with r colours, there exists a set H ∈ N^m, all of whose n-element subsets
have the same colour.

Comment: Seems obvious to me, but maybe that's because I don't know your definition of Ramsey numbers. Exactly how do you define the Ramsey Number for two natural numbers?

Comment: Pretty much the normal graph theory definition: Ramsey number R(m,n) is the minimum number of vertices required to construct a complete graph such that any 2-coloring of its edges produces a clique of size m of one color or a clique of size n of the other.

Comment: Don't you get the existence of the diagonal Ramsey number $R(m,m)$ by setting $n=r=2$ in that Corollary 2.3? Two-element sets of vertices are the same as edges, aren't they?

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right, but it says in the book later on that it implies existence for any set of two natural numbers (i.e. distinct natural numbers). Although the definition of Ramsey Numbers that they provide isn't even graph-theoretic. Maybe I should just learn Ramsey Theory somewhere else lol.

Comment: But the existence of $R(m,m)$ implies the existence of $R(n_1,n_2)$ for all $n_1,n_2\le m$, right?

Comment: No I don't think so. What makes you say that?

Comment: If there is a blue clique of size $m$ and if $n_1\le m$ then there is also a blue clique of size $n_1$. Also, if there is a red clique of size $m$ and if $n_2\le m$ then there is a red clique of size $n_2$.

Comment: Oh my god you're right. Okay I think it makes sense now. Thanks for explaining it better than my textbook